# Regarding Android Application Language

Tags: android

My problem is that i have a Diary application in which i am adding notes by selecting a particular date from Custom Calendar View.
The problem starts when user changes his phone language from English to any other, If user has selected Japanese as his phone's new language, Month's name would be converted in Japanese language. 
Now i want that if user selects any other language other than English than also Month's name should be shown in English only.
I searches a lot but could not find anything helpful.

Any positive response will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I think you should implement a custom calender view for that.

Comment: i've used custom calendar only, but my problem starts when user changes his device language, i want even if the device language change still the Month's name should be like January, February.. etc.

Comment: Can you paste snippet of your code so that I can have some idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use custom calender and when you display your calendar change `Locale`(Language) to English programatically.

[How to change Locale programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/1405983).

Hope it helps you.

**Edit :**

You can change Language using following code :

```
public void changeLang(String lang)
{
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
     return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    updateTexts();
}
```

Call this method by passing your language Like :

```
changeLang("en");
```

**Note** : You must define your string in `res/string.xml` file for **english** language. And you should set your string from `String.xml` not static.

For example for your concern Your calendar Names are set like...

```
yourtextview.getResources().getString(R.string.january);
```

Comment: Ok. i applied this code like this,                                                   Resources res = CalendarView.this.getResources();
      // Change locale settings in the app.
      DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
      android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
      conf.locale = new Locale("English");
      res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);        This is my class for Custom Calendar, but still after selecting Chinese language from my phone setting, it's showing month's name in Chinese only.

Comment: No error, but Month's name aren't getting displayed in English

Comment: See this example : http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html